# how to update a form from a thread

Tags: c#, multithreading

I am using mod bus protocol to retrieve data from the board. Now I want to update the data in window form all the time. But the label only update when I click button, any problem with my coding?

private void Call() {

```
        do
        {
            RequestData(); //get data from mod bus 
            run(a.ToString());


        } while (operation);

    }

    delegate void CallMethod(string Data);

    private void run(string data) {

        if (this.labelO2.InvokeRequired)
        {
            SetRichBoxCallBack d = new SetRichBoxCallBack(run);
            this.Invoke(d, new object[] { data });
        }
        else {
            labelO2.Text = data;
        }

    }
    Thread thread;
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        thread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(Call));
        thread.Start();

    }
   public void RequestData()
    {

        if (WriteSerialPort(setMessage, 0, 8))
        {
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
            for (i = 0; i < 19; i++)
            {

                MM[i] = (byte)serialPortBoard.ReadByte();


            }

            a = MM[11] << 8 | MM[12];
            b = (int)MM[13] << 8 | MM[14];


        }

    }
```

Comment: The call for the thread is on the `button1_Click` event? Please try to arrange your code it is all over the place

Comment: I edit it already. Sorry for the messy code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just the call to UI updates should be wrapped within `InvokeRequired ...` pattern - not the fetch of data from port. Also the `InvokeRequired...` pattern is missing else.

```
delegate void UIUpdate(object a, object b);

public void RequestData() {
  ...
  // set type and real value here ;)
  object a = null, b = null;
  var call = new UIUpdate((pa,pb) => {
      labelBin.Text = pa.ToString();
      labelO2.Text = pb.ToString();
  });
  if (this.InvokeRequired) {
    this.Invoke(call, a, b);
  } else {
    call.Invoke(a, b);
  }      
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  new Thread(() => {
    do {
      RequestData();  // get the data from mod bus protocol
    } while (operation);
  }).Start();    
}
```

**EDIT:**

Also there should be only one reader thread; which will do the reading; do not do write/read in one thread. The reader thread should be started on form load or in form constructor.

```
WriteSerialPort(setMessage, 0, 8)
```

Should be invoked directly on button click, while read should be always in single (separate) thread.

Comment: Just now I tried, but still can't update automatically. I have edited my code, can you go through again for me? Many thanks :)